# Partially applied type with kind (* -> Constraint)

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo f
class Bar b

newtype D d = D

call :: Proxy c -> (forall a . c a => a -> Bool) -> x -> Bool
call g x = g x

-- this function is Testable, and can be used by QuickCheck
f :: (Foo (D d), Bar d) => D d -> Bool
f = error ""

//assume the type FConstraint has kind (* -> Constraint)

main = print $ call (Proxy::Proxy FConstraint) (unsafeCoerce f) (D::D 17)
```

The intent of such a strange function is to be able to easily test polymorphic functions (such as `f`) using QuickCheck: `call` would be iterated over a type list of monomorphic types, and this list could be used for several different properties (all taking a single argument) without explicitly writing out type signatures each time. Since this is only appearing in test code, I'm willing to use `unsafeCoerce` (though I'm not sure it will do what I want at this point. I need to solve the question below first).

I'm certainly open to better/alternate designs for `call`, but here's my question about the solution I came up with above: I need a type `FConstraint` with kind `(* -> Constraint)` which can be used for the first argument to `call`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
type FConstraint x = (Foo x, Bar ??)
type FConstraint (D d) = (Foo (D d), Bar d)
```

Neither type synonym works, since I need to *pattern match on the type* to get all of the constraints, and also need to *partially apply* `FConstraint`, neither of which type synonyms allow.

I've also tried a type family:

```
type family FConstraint x
type instance FConstraint (D d) = (Foo (D d), Bar d)
```

but I still can't partially apply this (nor can I with a closed type family).

Thus I need a type of kind `(* -> Constraint)` which

- Pattern matches on the type of kind `*`
- Can be partially applied

---

**UPDATE**

Here's an almost-compiling example using the idea in the answer below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, ConstraintKinds, TypeOperators,
             MultiParamTypeClasses, DataKinds, PolyKinds, FlexibleInstances,
             UndecidableInstances, FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies,
             FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Prim
import GHC.TypeLits
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.Framework
import Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2
import Unsafe.Coerce

newtype Zq q = Zq Integer deriving (Show, Eq)

instance (KnownNat q) => Arbitrary (Zq q) where
  arbitrary = liftM (\i -> Zq $ (i `mod` (natVal (Proxy::Proxy q)))) arbitrary

instance (KnownNat q) => Num (Zq q) where
  (Zq a) + (Zq b) = Zq $ (a + b) `mod` (natVal (Proxy::Proxy q))
  (Zq a) * (Zq b) = Zq $ (a * b) `mod` (natVal (Proxy::Proxy q))
  negate (Zq 0) = (Zq 0)
  negate (Zq a) = Zq $ (natVal (Proxy::Proxy q)) - a
  fromInteger x = Zq $ x `mod` (natVal (Proxy::Proxy q))

f :: (KnownNat q) => Zq q -> Zq q
f x = x + 1

finv :: (KnownNat q) => Zq q -> Zq q
finv x = x - 1

prop_f :: forall q . (KnownNat q) => Zq q -> Bool
prop_f x = (finv . f) x == x

call :: (c x) => Proxy (c :: * -> Constraint) -> 
        (forall a . c a => a -> Bool) -> 
        x -> 
        Bool
call _ f = f

class UnZq zq q | zq -> q
instance UnZq (Zq q) q

class FConstraint x
instance (KnownNat q, UnZq zq q) => FConstraint zq

main = defaultMain $ [testProperty "zq_f_id" $ property $
         (call (Proxy::Proxy FConstraint) $ unsafeCoerce prop_f :: Zq 3 -> Bool)]
```

I get the error:

```
Could not deduce (KnownNat q0) arising from a use of ‘prop_f’
from the context (FConstraint a)
```

I'm hoping this is a simple scoping issue...

Here's more code for a use case:

```
type MyTypes = '[ Zq 3, Zq 5, Zq 7, Zq 11 ] 

class TypesToProps xs c where
  tmap :: Proxy xs -> Proxy c -> (forall a . c a => a -> Bool) -> [Property]

instance TypesToProps '[] c where
  tmap _ _ _ = []

instance (c x, TypesToProps xs c, Arbitrary x, Show x)
    => TypesToProps (x ': xs) c where
  tmap _ c f = (property (call c f :: x -> Bool)) : (tmap (Proxy::Proxy xs) c f)

-- results in same error as the `main` above
main = defaultMain $ map (testProperty "zq_f_id") $ 
         tmap (Proxy::Proxy MyTypes) 
              (Proxy::Proxy FConstraint) 
              (unsafeCoerce prop_f)
```

Comment: I've also looked at many other solutions for polymorphic QuickTesting, including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16794155/925978), but was unable to make it work for a type on which I needed to pattern match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your `call` function doesn't compile, nor should it: there is no way to infer `c x` in the type `Proxy c -> (forall a . c a => a -> Int) -> x -> Int` so you can't pass `x` to `f`.

Next, your use of `unsafeCoerce` is not valid here. If you look at the type of `unsafeCoerce` where you have used it:

```
withCall 
  :: (forall d . (Foo (D d), Bar d) => D d -> Bool) 
  -> (forall a . FConstraint a => a -> Int)
withCall = unsafeCoerce
```

You cast `D d` to *any type* and `Bool` to `Int`. (Note this requires ImpredictiveTypes). I don't understand your use case so I can't say if there is a better solution than `unsafeCoerce`, but I can say what you are doing will probably blow up in your face.

Writing the actual `FConstraint` is fairly easy:

```
class UnD x (y :: Nat) | x -> y 
instance UnD (D x) x 

class FConstraint x
instance (Foo x, Bar t, UnD x t) => FConstraint x
```

The complete code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    UndecidableInstances
  , ImpredicativeTypes
  , MultiParamTypeClasses
  , FunctionalDependencies 
  #-}

import Unsafe.Coerce 
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Proxy 
import GHC.TypeLits 

class Foo f
class Bar (b :: Nat)

data D (d :: Nat) = D

call :: Proxy (c :: * -> Constraint) -> (forall a . c a => a -> Int) -> x -> Int
call = undefined

f :: (Foo (D d), Bar d) => D d -> Bool
f = error ""

withCall :: (forall d . (Foo (D d), Bar d) => D d -> Bool) -> (forall a . FConstraint a => a -> Int)
withCall = unsafeCoerce

class UnD x (y :: Nat) | x -> y 
instance UnD (D x) x 

class FConstraint x
instance (Foo x, Bar t, UnD x t) => FConstraint x

main = print $ call (Proxy :: Proxy FConstraint) (withCall f) (D :: D 17)
```

---

In response to your update, the immediately obvious thing to do would be to refactor your `TypesToProps` class:

```
class TypesToProps xs (c :: k -> Constraint) (t :: k -> *) where
  tmap :: Proxy xs -> Proxy c -> Proxy t -> (forall a . c a => t a -> Bool) -> [Property]

instance TypesToProps '[] c t where
  tmap _ _ _ _ = []

instance (c x, TypesToProps xs c t, Arbitrary (t x), Show (t x)) => TypesToProps (x ': xs) c t where
  tmap _ c t f = property (f :: t x -> Bool) : tmap (Proxy :: Proxy xs) c t f

main = defaultMain $ map (testProperty "zq_f_id") $ 
  tmap (Proxy :: Proxy '[3, 5, 7, 11]) 
       (Proxy :: Proxy KnownNat) 
       (Proxy :: Proxy Zq)
       prop_f
```

This may not be general enough, but it requires no use of `unsafeCoerce`.

When you write `unsafeCoerce prop_f`, the type checker demands that the `KnownNat q` constraint be satisfied before it can do anything with it. You must either retain the constraint on the result type - which is fundamentally incompatible with what you are doing - or erase the constraint first.

You can store constraints as data (which is how they are stored internally anyways for polymorphic functions):

```
data Dict p where 
  Dict :: p => Dict p
```

We can erase constraints using this datatype:

```
anyDict :: Dict p 
anyDict = unsafeCoerce (Dict :: Dict (Eq ()))

prop_f' :: forall q . Zq q -> Bool
prop_f' q = case anyDict :: Dict (KnownNat q) of Dict -> prop_f q
```

In general this will be unsafe, but in this specific case it is actually safe, since the `q` in `Zq q` is a phantom parameter, and to use anything involving `Zq` you need to pick a concrete `q` anyways, which would remove the class constraint anyways.

Then you can write

```
class TypesToProps xs where
  tmap :: Proxy xs -> (forall a . a -> Bool) -> [Property]

instance TypesToProps '[] where
  tmap _ _ = []

instance (TypesToProps xs, Arbitrary x, Show x) => TypesToProps (x ': xs) where
  tmap _ f = property (f :: x -> Bool) : tmap (Proxy :: Proxy xs) f where
```

Note that the function `forall a . a -> Bool` is uninhabited, so you can only produce a value of that type using `unsafe` functions. This means that it is impossible to shoot yourself in the foot using `tmap` alone; unless you use an unsafe function, you will never even be able to instantiate `tmap`. Finally:

```
main = defaultMain $ map (testProperty "zq_f_id") $ 
  tmap (Proxy :: Proxy '[Zq 3, Zq 5, Zq 7, Zq 11]) 
       (unsafeCoerce prop_f' :: forall a . a -> Bool)
```

Comment: Cool trick with `UnD`. It's more work than I was hoping for (now you have to write an instance for every *type* you want to use, in addition to every test function), but it does the trick! As for the `unsafeCoerce`, the `Bool`/`Int` mismatch was a typo, but the idea with casting `D d` to any type is that I promise to use it in a context where the "any type" is a `D d`. I'm hoping that will work...

Comment: Do you really need `UnD`? Since it is only used in `FConstraint`, can't we just sub in `x=D d` and `t=d` into the `FConstraint` instance?