# QuickCheck: Testing every element in a finite set

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm looking for a way to test a function on a deterministic set of values *always* (rather than a randomly selected value from the list). For example, I'd like a way to check that

```
f :: (Num a) => a -> Bool
f x = (x - 2) == (x-3+1)
```

holds for exactly the `Int`s 1, 3, and 5, without explicitly writing out

```
testGroup "f tests" $ map (testProperty . property) [f (1::Int), f (3::Int), f (5::Int)]
```

Instead, I want to have some wrapper type around `Int` so that when I call `f` on this type, it tests `f` with the values 1,3, and 5 every time.

The motivation for this is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794155/925978) for testing polymorphic functions.

I came up with a solution using my own instance for `Arbitrary [Some c]`:

```
data Some c where
  Some :: (Show a, Arbitrary a, c a) => a -> Some c

instance Arbitrary [Dict c] => Arbitrary [Some c] where
  arbitrary = do
    dicts  :: [Dict c] <- arbitrary
    sequence $ map (\(Dict (Proxy::Proxy a)) -> liftM Some (arbitrary :: Gen a)) dicts


data Dict c where
  Dict :: (Show a, Arbitrary a, c a)
        => Proxy a -> Dict c

class ClassToTest a
  -- where ...    

instance Arbitrary [Dict ClassToTest] where
  arbitrary = return $ [Dict (Proxy::Proxy TYPE1),
                        Dict (Proxy::Proxy TYPE2)]

testAll :: forall a . (Arbitrary [a]) => (a -> Bool) -> Gen Bool
testAll f = do
  xs' <- arbitrary :: Gen [a]
  return $ and $ map f xs'
```

Then I could write a function

```
myTest :: (ClassToTest a) => a -> Bool
myTest x = error ""

theTest :: Test
theTest = testProperty "mytest" $ testAll myTest
```

which would generate an random value of `TYPE1` and run `myTest`, then generate a random value for `TYPE2` and run `myTest` again. The idea is that the list of TYPE* is very large, so I'd rather not rely on random selection to ensure everything in the list is being tested. The problem with my approach of course is that QuickCheck already has a generic instance for `(Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary [a]`, so this code requires `-XOverlappingInstances`. Is there a nicer way?

Comment: you could write a generic test-method (no need for QuickCheck here) that tests all inputs if those are instances of `Foldable` by just using [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:all) - maybe there is something like this around already and someone can point it out

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but the point of going through all of the hassle of writing `Some/Dict` is to reuse that long list of types without retyping them.

Comment: Isn't this more or less the entire point of the SmallCheck package?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid true SmallCheck will do this too ("up to some depth") - http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/smallcheck/

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why you give a type annotation to every element of the list, when just one will do, and why you don't map `f` over it. Maybe there's some issue that this trivial example doesn't reveal?

Comment: @dfeur One type won't do at all: I'm testing a polymorphic function on multiple different types, for example testing Zq arithmetic for different (type-level) moduli.